# Label and placeholder accessibility

Tags: html, label, forms, placeholder, screen-readers

I'm trying to find out if markup looks something like:

```html
<label for="cc">Credit card</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Credit card" id="cc">
```

Is there a scenario where "Credit card" will be announced twice by the screen reader?

I understand that the behavior might be different depending on the combination of browsers/screen readers, so I wonder if the general suggestion is to use only the `label` and to avoid duplication of the same text in `placeholder`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using placeholder text used in conjunction with a label. The problem is when the placeholder attribute gets used as a replacement for a label. Some screen-reader/browser combinations may read the placeholder in addition to the label, but I don't believe that's anything to be concerned about.

> " A placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label. The placeholder is a short hint intended to aid the user with data entry so it should not be identical to the label element. The placeholder may not be available to assistive technology and thus may not be relied upon to convey an accessible name or description"
>
> https://www.webaccessibility.com/best_practices.php?best_practice_id=2440

It's also worth noting that placeholder text should meet the contrast requirements of WCAG 2.0 SC 1.4.3.

https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html

Comment: Thanks, Josh. "The placeholder is a short hint intended to aid the user with data entry so it should not be identical to the label element." is a key part I was looking for. I assume it is annoying for the user to hear a duplicated announcement of each field in case their reader repeats placeholder after label. If a form has a lot of those fields I think a user experience might be not great compared to a scenario when only labels are used. It would be really great if there are accessibility experts who can confirm if this behaviour is common for assistive technologies that are used nowadays.